# How to get range assigned to Named Range in excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba, named-ranges

I have already defined the named ranges in my workbook. I want to use the range for placing my pie chart. I am trying to write a code which sets range to variable and move the chart to the specific location.

```
Dim Rng As Range
Dim ChtObj As ChartObject

Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Name("BT_GATE1").RefersTo
Set ChtObj = ActiveChart.Parent
ChtObj.Top = Rng.Top
```

I think I am missing something or using a worng method. Can some one help me assigning a range to variable 'Rng'?

Comment: `Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Name("BT_GATE1").RefersToRange`

Comment: Thanks Chris. But I am getting Compile Error as Worng numebr of arguments or invalid property assignment. I want the code to return range 'OUTPUT!$F$44:$I$60' which is assigned to named range 'BT_GATE1'.

Comment: Hi Siddharth, I think that will assign values with in 'OUTPUT!$F$44:$I$60' to the range. I think I want some function which will return a string as "OUTPUT!$F$44:$I$60" which I can use further.

Comment: I didn't notice this first time,  I think it's `Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Names("BT_GATE1").RefersToRange` with an `s`

Comment: Did you check my answer? Or rather did you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A named range is either one cell or a collection of more cells which have been given a name. Ultimately it is a range. So in your case you can directly set it to a range as shown below

```
Dim Rng As Range

Set Rng = Range("BT_GATE1")

Debug.Print Rng.Address
Debug.Print Rng.Top
Debug.Print Rng.Parent.Name
```

Comment: Hi Siddharth Yes It is working. I mean at least there is no compile error. My chart is moving but not as I want to. I think I am missing something. Let me know if we can chat in person so that I can share entire code and the output desired.

Comment: `Let me know if we can chat in person so that I can share entire code and the output desired. – Vidish Soman 1 hour ago` If you are looking for free consultation then I would recommend posting your questions here so that not only I but others can also chip in and help you out. :) If you are looking for paid consultation then please feel free to click [THIS](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/contact/)

Comment: Thanks you Siddharth. Solution you provided worked. I could also move pie charts as per criteria within specified range with below code `Dim Rng As Range
Dim ChtObj As ChartObject

Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Name("BT_GATE1").RefersTo
Debug.Print Rng.Address
    Debug.Print Rng.Top
    Debug.Print Rng.Parent.Name
    Set ChtObj = ActiveChart.Parent
    ChtObj.Top = Rng.Top
    ChtObj.Left = Rng.Left` But the charts overlap at same point. Is there any way I can place charts randomly with the range?

Comment: Please post a new question with the link to this question with more details and screenshots if possible and I or others will definitely reply there :)

Comment: Please post a new question with the link to this question with more details and screenshots if possible and I or others will definitely reply there :)